# Do pages have set minimum height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reduce my page height but it doesn't work.

So I've tried to move my footer up, but this just leaves a space between the footer and the bottom where, strangely, elements appear to have found a new footer and are interacting with it. (not going below etc.)

How is this possible and why can i increase my page height, but not decrease it under a certain height?

There are two elements which control my front page, one is the page id "28" the other is an element called "parallax-window".

Neither of the two elements are responding to page reductions. Element `.page-id-28` responds to increase in height but not decrease,. `parallax-window` responds to css color change but not to height instructions.

So basically, what I want to know is, what is ultimately controlling my page height amd why won't it go under a certain height but happily go as high as I want.

When I turned `.parallax-window` green, there was a black space underneath which im assuming is my actual page, defined by id `28`.

I've tried to unset my footer position, to no avail and tried negative height for `.parallax-window` and `.page-id-28.`

So here is my html:

```
<div class="parallax-window fullscreen" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/download-2.png" data-ios-fix="true" data-over-scroll-fix="true" data-android-fix="true">
<div class="align-transform">
```

I tried:

```
@media (min-width:768px)
{.parallax-window{ height: 
500px;}}

@media (min-width:768px)
{.page-id-28{height: 
500px;}}

@media (min-width:768px)
{body, html.page-id- 
28{height: 500px;}}
```

Nothing.

[page here desktop](https://4309.co.uk)

Perhaps elements on the page are increasing the height, but I should still be able to reduce the height. I've made element "parallax-window" green to make it clearer.

Comment: Remove the dot in your @media lines. That doesn't belong there.

Comment: What you call "element with ID 28" is the [HTML Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) which contains all elements defined in your web page whereas the `parallax-window` is simply a container. The body is defined by the amount of elements contained in it so you need to find out which elements stretch the page to the height it has. There are also some errors in your page code (missing tags).

Comment: Exactly. Which elements have stretched my page? But i should still be able to reduce the page height regardless..?

Comment: It's container `#content` holding (besides other elements) `#shapely_home_parallax-2` (956px) and `#text-52` (666px) that lead to a total page height of 2078 pixels.

Comment: Great. What should i do? I've turned `parallax-window` green to make it clearer.

Comment: Please post a [mre] of the code on Stack Overflow (you can use Stack Snippets [icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar]), not just a link to a site that will change and render the question useless to future visitors.

Comment: @SaschaM78 I reduced height of #text-52. Brilliant dude. Thanks.